# Progressive web app unable to download files

Tags: ionic-framework, iframe, moodle, progressive-web-apps, pwabuilder

Good day

I am currently trying to develop a progressive web app for a Moodle site, but I am unable to download files from the Moodle site.

I made use of https://www.pwabuilder.com/ to build the PWA and generate the service workers. I added the service workers to the https Moodle site, as required. The service workers are registered as they should be when using the PWA.

The PWA work perfectly for opening external links soos as URLs (URLs open in the app browser as needed).

I am however unable to download any files such as pdf documents from the moodle site.

I tried to develop an Ionic app with a basic iframe which embeds the Moodle site in order to determine if that would work. I was able to open external links as well, but still unable to open/download documents.

I then embedded the following website http://www.pdfpdf.com/samples/ in an iframe in an Ionic app, which hosts some sample pdf files. I was then able to download the pdf documents as needed.

I them embedded another website from another server that we have, but was also unable to download any documents

When emulating the Ionic app in a browser, I have always been able to download files as needed, as it is just another "browser" accessing the files.

So my guess is that some configuration on the server is blocking the download of files when requested from an app such as a progressive web app?

Any help or pointers would be highly appreciated.